# What's the proper term for "brain waves" read from an EEG?

Tags: terminology, electroencephalography

An EEG records the electrical activity of the brain. An EEG shows voltage differences as a function of time and shows what have become known as "*brain waves*".

**Is there a scientific/technical word/phrase for one of these measured "brain waves"?**

Comment: fyi: galvanic skin responses are not the same as EEG - I edited the question therefore to prevent confusion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The terminology around EEGs is variable, dependent on the context;

- **Brain wave** is fine, but has a bit of a popular undertone;
- **Oscillation**, as per the deleted answer,  implicitly refers to a longer-term behavior, *i.e.*, something periodic (EEG);
- **Waveform** is often used to describe a single event with a recognizable shape (ERP, compound action potentials, etc.);
- **EEG signal/recording/trace** is more than fine too, it doesn't carry any implicit meaning about its nature, it does carry relevant information on the method used;
- **EEG** is fine too, EEG means electroencephalogram, the '[gram](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/-gram)' suffix comes from Greek, where it means “something written,” or a “drawing”, so literally it means something like "graph of the electrical brain". So simply speaking of 'the EEG' is OK as well.

<sub>This list may not be exhaustive, merely illustrative</sub>